# iOS Accessibility -- doing something on flick?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, accessibility

Is it possible to capture the accessibility VoiceOver single finger flick? I want to update my `accessibilityElements` array only after the user has seen a specific element.

**Background:**

I manually set my `accessibilityElements` array to the `visibleCells()` in my collection view, followed by the `done` button of my view. Once the user has reached the `done` button, though, I want the user to have the opportunity to continue scrolling (just like a normal user would), but I don't know how, at the point where the user has reached the `done` accessibility element, to push new `visible cells` into the `accessibilityElements` array.

**Code:** 
Just to give more context, this is what I'm doing:

```
    var accessibilityElements : [UIView] = myCollectionView.visibleCells()
    accessibilityElements.append(doneButton)
    view.accessibilityElements = accessibilityElements
```

This is all happening in my `viewDidAppear` method. Is there a way to do the same thing in a spot after having accessibility swiped to the `doneButton`?

**Attempted Approach:**

I attempted to use `UIAccessibilityFocus` protocol, but the view I'm attempting to check the focus on is a `UIButton`, and I don't want to subclass `UIButton` to implement this method just for accessibility. Would there be another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the `accessibilityScroll` method, and do the changing of the `view`'s `accessibilityElements` array in there.

From the docs:

```
Scrolls screen content in an application-specific way and returns the success or failure of the action.
    func accessibilityScroll(_ direction: UIAccessibilityScrollDirection) -> Bool
Parameters
    direction   
         A constant that specifies the direction of the scrolling action. See UIAccessibilityScrollDirection for descriptions of valid constants.
```

[Link to docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityAction_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/accessibilityScroll:)

So I basically override this method for my collection view, and suggest to my user to "three finger swipe" to get this behavior, which is what causes `accessibilityScroll` to be called. I always return true, and do the appropriate animations for swiping on my cells that should be taking place.

PS. The `.Next` and `.Previous` `direction` values never happened for me, I only got `.Right` and `.Left`.